# How to add maxItemsInObjectGraph programmatically without using configuration file?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wcf-configuration, wcf-endpoint

I have create a EndpointAddress like that

```
EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress("http://example.com/services/OrderService.svc");
```

But I could not add the Behavior to this Endpoint programmatically.

The behavior is given below.:

```
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="NewBehavior">
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="6553600" />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Answer (score 29):

On the server you have to add it in the ServiceBehavior Attribute:

```
 [ServiceBehavior(MaxItemsInObjectGraph = int.MaxValue)]
```

On the client you have to apply it to the endpoint. In this example you can see how to add it to all the endpoints in your ChannelFactory:

```
var factory = new ChannelFactory<IInterface>(...);
foreach (OperationDescription op in factory.Endpoint.Contract.Operations)
    {
        var dataContractBehavior = op.Behaviors.Find<DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior>();
        if (dataContractBehavior != null)
        {
            dataContractBehavior.MaxItemsInObjectGraph = int.MaxValue;
        }
    }
```

Comment: But note that if you are implementing your own DataOntrolSerializerOperationBehavior, for example, to preserve cycle references, you must specify the MaxItemsInObjectGraph in the constructor to DataContractSerializer.

Answer (score 2):

On Server Side， you can also:

```
ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost();
ServiceBehaviorAttribute sba = host .Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceBehaviorAttribute>();
            if (sba == null)
            {
                sba = new ServiceBehaviorAttribute();
                sba.MaxItemsInObjectGraph = int.MaxValue;
                host.Description.Behaviors.Add(sba);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative: `((ServiceBehaviorAttribute) host.Description.Behaviors[typeof(ServiceBehaviorAttribute)]).MaxItemsInObjectGraph = int.MaxValue;`